# Socket com Timertask

Tags: java, socket

Quero solicitar do `serverSocket` uma resposta (algumas informações) a cada 5 segundos.

Montei meu `socket` e estou usando um `TimerTask` para executar a cada 5 segundos um método, porém apenas a primeira execução é bem sucedida.

## Tentativa um

Chamar o método completo e dentro desse método o socket é criado e fechado na finalização do mesmo.

**Código TimerTask**

```
public void run() {
   SocketeClient() mCommand = new SocketClient();
   mCommand.runClient();
}
```

**Código Socket**

```
public void runClient() {

   System.out.println("---------------------");
   try {
      client = new Socket("localhost", 9999);

      input = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
      output = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());

      byte request[] = new byte[18];
      output.write(request, 0, 17);

      int totalBytes = input.available();
      byte response[] = new byte[totalBytes];
      boolean continuar = true;
      int bytesLer = 0;

      while (continuar && bytesLer < totalBytes) {
         try {
            response[bytesLer] = input.readByte();
            bytesRead++;
         } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            reading = false;
         }
      }

      System.out.println(response[0] + response[1]);

      input.close();
      output.close();
      socket.close();
   } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
   System.out.println("---------------------");
}
```

Nesse exemplo, só existe retorno na primeira execução, todas as demais execuções que ocorrem a cada 5 segundos não tem retorno. A porta local está mudando. Exemplo: 55147, depois 55148 e sucessivamente.

**Console eclipse:**

```
----------------------------------------------------
Cliente: Socket[addr=localhost/127.0.0.1,port=9999,localport=52206]
05,45
-----------------------------------------------------

----------------------------------------------------
Cliente: Socket[addr=localhost/127.0.0.1,port=9999,localport=52206]
Infelizmente não houve resposta do servidor.
-----------------------------------------------------

----------------------------------------------------
Cliente: Socket[addr=localhost/127.0.0.1,port=9999,localport=52206]
Infelizmente não houve resposta do servidor.
-----------------------------------------------------
```

## Tentativa dois

Tentei usar outra abordagem, pensei em passar um objeto `Socket` para o método, assim não teria que ficar criando e fechando, usaria o mesmo para receber o valor a cada 5 segundos, mas recebo o seguinte erro a partir da segunda execução e não estou usando "client.close()" já que pretendo usar sempre o mesmo objeto Socket.

**Erro**

```
java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
    at java.net.Socket.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.iamExport.model.MessageCommands.apiGetAudienceStatus(MessageCommands.java:29)
    at com.iamExport.model.ConnectionSocket.Connectar(ConnectionSocket.java:36)
    at com.iamExport.model.ConnectionSocket.run(ConnectionSocket.java:26)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

## Observações

1. O servidor fica rodando, tudo que tentei falhou, a ideia é mandar bytes para ele, e o mesmo me retornar outros bytes. A primeira abordagem tenta criar novos `socket`s e a segunda usar o mesmo `socket`. Estou tentando me comunicar com um intervalo de tempo.
2. Tentei explicar meu problema e necessidade que tenho. Acredito estar no caminho, mas falta alguma coisa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apesar de você não ter disponibilizado o código do seu servidor, a descrição do seu problema parece implicar que o mesmo não está preparado para receber conexões em sequência. Ou seja, sempre que seu cliente encerra o primeiro Socket, o **ServerSocket** é fechado e a partir da segunda conexão não existe "ninguém" esperando novas conexões.

Se este for o caso, uma solução simples é fazer algo assim:

```
ServerSocket serveridor = new ServerSocket(porta);
while(true) {
    Socket cliente = servidor.accept();
    //iniciar_uma_thread_pra_cuidar_deste(cliente)
}
```